# Bind dictionary of attributes on element definition

Tags: javascript, attributes, polymer

I am trying to bind a dictionary of attributes like `{'id': 'myid', 'class': 'my-1 pr-md-2', ...}` at the time I am defining the element. I do not want to set that attributes after the DOM is loaded by Javascript.

I am struggling with the correct form of doing this. I can not bind them one by one declaring the attribute name and value manually as they are user given parameters. I have think of appending them to the `attributes` property, but I do not know if it is advisable to do it this way.

This is my data structure:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{links}}" as="link">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link mr-md-2" on-tap="changePage">{{link.title}}</a>
</template>
```

and the attributes are saved in each `link.attributes` property. My solution would be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{links}}" as="link">
    <a attributes={{appendAttributes(link)}} class="nav-item nav-link mr-md-2" on-tap="changePage">{{link.title}}</a>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
appendAttributes: function(link){
    //Get current attributes of the element and append the ones in link.attributes
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle it?

Comment: What version of Polymer are you using?

Comment: I'm using Polymer 3.0 @Umbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible with Polymer's templating system: [there's no way](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4284#issuecomment-276379235) to access the element to which a computed binding is applied to.

This

```html
<a attributes={{appendAttributes(link)}}></a>
```

can't work because the `attributes` property is [read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element#targetText=Element.attributes).

> I can not bind them one by one declaring the attribute name and value manually as they are user given parameters

Actually if you know in advance *what* attributes/properties have to be set you can still set them dynamically:

```html
<a id=[[userGivenId]]
   class$=[[userGivenClass]]
   ...
></a>
```

Anyway, there is a `lit-html` directive made by `open-wc` called [spread](https://open-wc.org/developing/lit-helpers.html#spread-directives) which does just what you want. This would require rewriting your component using LitElement to something like this:

```js
import { LitElement, html, property, customElement } from 'lit-element';
import { repeat } from 'lit-html/directives/repeat';
import { spread } from '@open-wc/lit-helpers';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @property() userGivenId;
  @property() links;
  // ...

  render() {
    return html`

      ${repeat(this.links, link => html`

        <a ...=${spread({
             id: this.userGivenId,
             '?my-boolean-attribute': true
             '.myProperty': { foo: 'bar' },
             '@my-event': () => console.log('my-event fired'),
           })}
           class="nav-item nav-link mr-md-2" 
           @click=${e => this.changePage(e)}
        >${link.title}</a>

      `)}

    `;
  }
}
```

With some limitations, `PolymerElement`s and `LitElement`s can coexist in the same project so converting a single component shouldn't cause any trouble.